# Pausing a python script until an environment variable in another program is created

Tags: python

I have the following windows batch command configured in a Jenkins pipeline.

python workspace\script.py "cmd /c call workspace\main.bat". 
The script.py needs to use an environment variable(DEBUG) created in main.bat. Since the environment variable is created by the main.bat after the execution of the script.py, I am not able to use the environment variable in the script.py. Is there anyway that I could pause the script.py program and continue once the environment variable is created main.bat

Comment: this sounds like some circular dependency

Comment: This isn't possible. Why are you doing this? It really sounds like the wrong thing to be trying to fix.

Comment: You need to use some form of inter process communication to get information from `main.bat` to `script.py`. For instance create/wait for file with desired content; or use a pipe;...